# What is the fastest way to convert correlation between a vector and a matrix in r?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, correlation

I am trying to find a fast way to calculate the correlation between a vector of values and a matrix.  I have a data frame with 200 rows and 400,000 observations after transposing the data.  I need to find the cor between each column and every other column.

My code is below but it is too slow.  Can anyone come up with a faster way.

```
for(i in 1:400000){
      x=cor(trainDataNew[,i],trainDataNew[,-i])
}
```

You don't need my data to do this.  You can create random data like below.

```
norm1 <- rnorm(1000)
norm2 <- rnorm(1000)
norm3 <- rnorm(1000)
as.data.frame(cbind(norm1,norm2,norm3))
```

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with

```
cc <- cor(trainDataNew)
```

?

If you only want the lower triangle you can then use

```
cc2 <- cc[lower.tri(cc,diag=FALSE)]
```

---

[This blog post](https://rmazing.wordpress.com/2013/02/22/bigcor-large-correlation-matrices-in-r/) claims to have done a similar-sized (slightly smaller) problem in about a minute. Their approach is implemented in `HiClimR::fastCor`.

```
library(HiClimR)
system.time(cc <- fastCor(dd, nSplit = 10, 
        upperTri = TRUE, verbose = TRUE,
        optBLAS=TRUE))
```

I haven't gotten this working yet (keep running out of memory), but you may have better luck.  You should also look into linking R to an optimized BLAS, e.g. see [here](https://gist.github.com/nicebread/6920c8287d7bffb03007) for MacOS.

Someone [here](https://brainchronicle.blogspot.com/2013/02/large-correlation-in-parallel.html) reports a parallelized version (code is [here](https://gist.github.com/bobthecat/5024079), along with some forked versions)

Comment: I have a 400,000 column data frame.  That would make a 400,000 columns by 400,000 row matrix.  I would run out of memory.                                                                                                           I just ran cor with 50,000 columns and got Error: cannot allocate vector of size 18.6 Gb

Comment: You mean that you don't need to store those values? You would use them on the fly in your loop?